# Hashmap to Function<string, string> to Hashmap?

Tags: java, function

Currently have code that initializes a `Function<String, Object> lookup` variable:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
...
lookup = map::get;
```

Is it possible to derive the HashMap from this `lookup` variable? According to (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) there may not be. Possibly a domain getter and an output getter for `Function<String, Object>` types?

Comment: I can't figure out what do you want to do, but I try to guess maybe that: Map<String, Function<String, Object>>. There is getting the function from Map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might or might not feasible: when Java generate the lambda, it creates an implementation of `Function` which reference variables used by the lambda as synthetic fields. Since the lambda is `map::get`, there is a synthetic field for the `map`.

Using this code and [jdoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/), or any java 11 compiler:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
       Function<String, String> lookup = map::get;
       
       System.out.println(lookup);
       System.out.println(lookup.getClass());
       for (Field field : lookup.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
           System.out.println(field); 
       }
    }
}
```

If you execute the code, you should see a field:

```
MyClass$$Lambda$1/0x0000000100060c40@4c3e4790
class MyClass$$Lambda$1/0x0000000100060c40
private final java.util.Map MyClass$$Lambda$1/0x0000000100060c40.arg$1
```

The `MyClass$$Lambda$1/0x0000000100060c40.arg$1` is the reference to map.

As you can see, the name is generated and not very easy to predict: you could certainly assume "somewhere" that if there is one field of type Map, then it *may* be the map used in `map::get`.

The field is private and with Java 11, you don't know the module of the generated class: you may not even access it using reflection (or `java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle`).

The short answer is no, it is not reasonably possible. Neither I think you should try to do it unless you want to know how it works.